# Ajax form submit calling method twice in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a weird scenario happens when I send my ajax request that has 2 objects 
first time it passes the second obj with the right value while the first object is null.Then second call it passes the first obj with value and the second obj as null

Here's my ajax method

```
var serializedForm = $(form).serialize();
var postData = {
    merchTask: obj,
    items: arrItems
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $(form).attr('action'),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    success: function (response) { 
        alert('done');
    },
     error: function (xhr, status, error) {
         alert("Oops..." + xhr.responseText);
     }
});
```

And here's my action in controller

```
    public ActionResult EditTask(Task merchTask, string[] items)
    {
        short CompanyID = Convert.ToInt16((gSessions.GetSessionValue(gSessionsData.Company) as Company).ID);
        try
        { 
            merchTask.CompanyID = CompanyID; 
            if (merchTask.TaskID != 0)
            {
                taskTemplatesBF.Update(merchTask);
            }
            else
            {
                taskTemplatesBF.InsertMerchTask(merchTask);
            } 
            string[] selectedLst = items;
            foreach (string item in selectedLst)
            { 
                taskTemplatesBF.InsertItemsLink(CompanyID,merchTask.TaskID,merchTask.ItemCode);
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("TasksTemplates", "Merch");

    }
```

*I found a workaround to send each object separately in different ajax 
but what's wrong  when I send them in one request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have added a lot of code in the question but missed the code that was actually needed.

Okay add the `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` functions inside your form summit event as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("formId").on('submit',function(event){

       event.preventDefault();
       event.stopImmediatePropagation();


       var serializedForm = $(form).serialize();
       var postData = {
             merchTask: obj,
             items: arrItems
        };

       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType:'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(postData),
            success: function (response) { 
                   alert('done');
             },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert("Oops..." + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });    
  });
});
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has saved my day, rather days!